# Url rewrite in IIS for different domain to call multiple service based on url

Tags: asp.net, iis, url-rewriting, iis-10

i have multiple services running on a server on domain abc.com and my web application is running on different server xyz.com. I have a requirement wherein I need to write urlrewrite in such a way that if I type

- xyz.com/service1 -> it should call service1 which is running on  abc.com:1234 same way if i type
- xyz.com/service2 -> it should call/redirect to service2 running on abc.com:5678 and so on.

how to write the url rewrite for it?

I am using IIS version 10 window server 2022

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use a reverse proxy, the following case you can use as a reference:

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Reverse Proxy to service1" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="(.*)" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{SERVER_PORT}" pattern="1234" />
          </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="http://x.com/service1" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="Reverse Proxy to service2" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="(.*)" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{SERVER_PORT}" pattern="5678" />
          </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="http://x.com/service2" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

More information you can refer to this link: [Reverse Proxy with URL Rewrite v2 and Application Request Routing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-v2-and-application-request-routing).

Comment: Thank for your reply. but i think its kind of not working I am getting 404 error. I will explain how i have done. First i have installed ARR and URl Rewrite Then enabled Reverse Proxy in ARR at the root node level. then i have created URL rewrite rule on newly created website  as mentioned above. and i am getting 404 error.  i have service running on domain for example domain.com:port1, domain.com:port2 so on. now from my reverse proxy i need to access these services . How can i access these services.

Comment: Regarding 404 errors, you can use [failed request tracing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis) to view detailed error information and resolve it base on detail log, reverse proxy is your best choice.

Comment: xyz.com/service1  where service1 is nothing and it is not pointing to any sub domain/folder.
i am able to redirect from xyz.com to abc.com:1234 but i want to achieve like
xyz.com/service1 should redirect to abc.com:1234. 

but it seems not working when i am adding /service1 in the url.

Comment: You can still use failed request tracing to see what the problem is.